# In Java, how do I convert a hex string to a byte[]?

Tags: java, hex

I am using the below function in Java to convert an encrypted String into hex format:

```
public static String toHex(byte [] buf) {
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
            strbuf.append("0");
        }
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return strbuf.toString();
}
```

Now I want to convert that hex string back into a byte array. How can I do that?

For example,

```
(1) Plain Text = 123
(2) Encrypted Text = «h>kq*«¬Mí“~èåZ  \}?
(3) Encrypted Text in Hex = f263575e7b00a977a8e9a37e08b9c215feb9bfb2f992b2b8f11e
```

I can go from `(2)` to `(3)`, but how do I go from `(3)` back to `(2)`?

Comment: aa to Ra. One Movie no kamal chhe. you can join me in my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Comment: What's a Back byte array?  Is that different from a byte array?

Comment: How to convert binary/byte string into hex? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603046/decrypt-string-in-java-which-was-encrypted-using-symmetric-key-in-php/29603246?noredirect=1#29603046

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
 String s="f263575e7b00a977a8e9a37e08b9c215feb9bfb2f992b2b8f11e";
 byte[] b = new BigInteger(s,16).toByteArray();
```

Comment: This did not give me the result I was looking for, but the simple one-liner method in dARKpRINCE's response did.

Comment: `cs.setBytes(1,new BigInteger(regReportId,16).toByteArray());`

this worked when i have to pass RAW datatype to Oracle sproc

Comment: The `new BigInteger(s,16).toByteArray();` is not correct. I input a 34-length hex string, and output a 18-length bytes. What I want is a 17-length bytes

Comment: I think this gives wrong result sometimes. for instance, it gives 17 bytes for A85565ED63B893F5A3EF85D88819D484. but it should be 16 bytes

Comment: this gives the wrong results; DarkPrince "util method" works correctly for me.

Answer (score 116):

**The accepted answer does not consider leading zeros which may cause problems**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java) answers it. Depending on whether you want to see how its done or just use a java built-in method. Here are the solutions copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/2791703) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942951/2791703) answers respectively from the SO question mentioned.

**Option 1: Util method**

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                             + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

**Option 2: One-liner build-in**

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(array);
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
}
```

Comment: your answer help me with http://stackoverflow.com/a/25790612/173149, thanks +1

Comment: +1 for the one-liner option using classes already provided with Java.

Comment: For the string `56276BE1`, it gives me bytes of `86, 39, 107, -31`. But an other application written in C# gives me `86, 39, 107, 225` for the same hex string. Which one is true?

Comment: Both are correct. C# handles bytes differently than Java. In Java byte value is between -127 and 127, while C# has 0 to 255.

Comment: The one-liner built-in seems to be not-so-built-in anymore on Java 9 though, as simply importing `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` does not work.

Comment: as of Java 17 there is now an officially provided method `java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(s)`

Answer (score 6):

I found that the DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary is more costly (two times) than:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex(str.toCharArray())
```

Comment: This is more costly than DatatypeConverter, since Apache commons is an additional library (dependency, size, etc) - while DatatypeConverter is part of the JDK.