# Decrypt string in java which was encrypted using AES in php

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

```
<?php
    # --- ENCRYPTION ---

    # the key should be random binary, use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2 to
    # convert a string into a key
    # key is specified using hexadecimal

    $length = 16;
    $key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    // echo $key;

    // $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");
    echo $key."<br/>";

    echo "<br/>";
    # show key size use either 16, 24 or 32 byte keys for AES-128, 192
    # and 256 respectively
    $key_size =  strlen($key);
    echo "Key size: " . $key_size;
    echo "<br/>";

    $plaintext = "This string was AES-256 / CBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted.";

    # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    # creates a cipher text compatible with AES (Rijndael block size = 128)
    # to keep the text confidential 
    # only suitable for encoded input that never ends with value 00h
    # (because of default zero padding)
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                 $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

    # encode the resulting cipher text so it can be represented by a string
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

    echo  "ENCRYPTED DATA =". $ciphertext_base64;
    echo "<br/>";

    # === WARNING ===

    # Resulting cipher text has no integrity or authenticity added
    # and is not protected against padding oracle attacks.

    # --- DECRYPTION ---

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);

    # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
    $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

    # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
    $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
    $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                    $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

    echo  "DECRYPTED TEXT = ".$plaintext_dec;
?>
```

JAVA :-

```
public static String decryptWithIV(byte[] key, String encrypted)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    if (key.length != 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(
            new byte[16]));
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted
            .getBytes()));

    return new String(original);
}
```

When I run the PHP code I get below 2 details which I copied to my java code.

```
public static final String KEY = "œ8[,#BÌüïmÕe-<Æ   1^Ž—½R™t3§¡ÚI";
    public static final String ENCRYPTED_DATA = "ASfLnSMyfp9vHN2UTO4TRilUIRywzVfJfrfkrp4gPsP0+lENwEHJ3/YzstfuIESgVFfpkxHGTxuiO+aWZObG5aPoZfrcoIDQLVXeRiysA4s=";
```

The issue is my key already in byte (When run on localhost), but in my java code its again trying to convert it into byte. I would like to know How can I initialize byte array as I have the key with me from localhost as of now.

Comment: You use CBC mode in PHP but ECB in Java as well as different padding.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry for all caps, I just wanted my comments to readable.

Comment: @AlexK. I am new in Security, can you please guide me in right direction to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your code.

- Your key in Java is only 31 characters long and not 32. Bytes cannot be always represented as a string, because there are sometimes non-prinable characters. You can print your key as hex with `bin2hex()` or as base64 with `base64_encode()` and reverse the process in Java like [this (hex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890174/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte) or with `Base64.decodeBase64()`.
- Use the same mode of operation and padding like in PHP. That is use `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"`. Since PHP uses ZeroPadding, you will then need to remove the zero bytes at the end after decryption.
- The IV is prepended to the ciphertext in PHP, but you don't slice the IV off in Java. Also, you provide a zero byte IV.

```
public static String decryptWithIV(byte[] key, String encrypted)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    if (key.length != 16) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }

    byte[] ciphertextBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes());
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ciphertextBytes, 0, 16);
    ciphertextBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(ciphertextBytes, 16,
            ciphertextBytes.length);

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(ciphertextBytes);

    // remove zero bytes at the end
    int lastLength = original.length;
    for (int i = original.length - 1; i > original.length - 16; i--) {
        if (original[i] == (byte) 0) {
            lastLength--;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return new String(original, 0, lastLength);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my KEY is already in byte. The issue is currently I am working on local server, where first I run the PHP code and get the symmetric key and encrypted data. From there I copy and paste both in java strings. I think the problem is my KEY is already in byte as I am using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes PHP function which returns random bytes.

Comment: Yes, you should encode it first into hex or base64.

Comment: String hex = Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(
    "·ñ+«r–àA‘ªNdàÎ·Ao§‹µå[üúÎ„d6‹:", 2)); - This is giving me number format exception. I think its not recognizing the bytes as valid format.

Comment: You need to encode the key into hex/base64 on the php side, copy it to the Java program and then decode it back into a byte array.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Just last thing, I got my decrypted string but it has some added data on start and end.

RESULT - ””Íè7}?Vÿª¼MaÎAgThis string was AES-256 / CBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted. 

I have updated the decryption function as well.

Comment: I added a proper IV handling and an example for Java code.

Comment: Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on -> if (original[i] == (byte) 0) {

Comment: Was a typo. It should be `i--` not `i++`

Comment: Its returning wrong output now with updated code, don't know what goes wrong here. Output is like é²ý@Ê“Ý­ÜWœFshh^€ø—ÊaÝŸŸä‡<‘^h^€ø—ÊaÝŸŸä‡<‘^h^€ø—ÊaÝŸŸä‡<‘^. Earlier code is still working but having added values on start and end. I am debugging the code, if you can find the problem in code written please kindly update me.