# Convert bytes to String

Tags: java, android, string, byte

We receive from bluetooth device this output: 
  byte[] bytes = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA).getBytes();

and the output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHyfs.png)

How I can transform bytes[] to String[] in format HEX without losing "CE" chars in the picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your bytes are just plain text, then you can do

```
new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

If your bytes create a hex string, convert that hex string to another `byte[]` by doing

```
new String(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(new String(bytes)), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I can call DatatypeConverter in android?

Comment: Ah, my bad. You can either shade a library which supports conversion or use a method from another StackOverflow answer such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119453/4490686)