# Converting HexString to Bytes and then Back to HexString adds extra zero

Tags: java, hex, byte, arrays

Am converting a 64 bit/16 hex string to byte array but it seems am not doing the conversion well. 
What am I doing wrong? 
So my string is `FEDCBA9876543210` but when I convert it to `byteArray` it is 9 bytes long instead of 8! 
On converting it back, I get `00FEDCBA9876543210`

What am I doing wrong. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890174/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte) was used in my function.
Here is my code for the conversion.

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    byte [] data = new byte[len/2];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i+=2) {
        data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 16) << 4) +
                (Character.digit(str.charAt(i+1), 16)));
    }
    return data;
}
```

This is the code for converting back.

```
public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte [] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];

    for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
        int c = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[i*2] = hexArray[c >>> 4];
        hexChars[i*2 + 1] = hexArray[c & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Comment: Show us the *converting back* function, the above code looks good considering you create byte array of size len/2, so it is impossible to put there 9*2 bytes instead of 8*2 if the input was 16 chars.

Comment: Are you sure the code you are running and the code you are showing are the same? Cause, for me using Java 8, assertEquals(8, buf.length) is true.

Comment: @krzyk Not that it changes in, but I have added it. Try it on your end.

Comment: @wallenborn Yes the code is the came. Try it with that string I added. My path says Java SDK is "1.8.0_60"

Comment: Your code looks OK. The problem must be somewhere else. Are you sure that the input string's length is exactly 16 characters and that there are no hidden extra characters?

Comment: I also tried running the code by using: `System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(hexStringToByteArray("FEDCBA9876543210")));` and it outputs `fedcba9876543210`.
You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: Yes I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a terrible mistake. 
Somewhere after the conversion, I was reconverting the BigInteger value of this with BigInteger.toByteArray conversion. (Don't ask me why!!) Remnants of previous work.

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--), conversion to byte array adds one sign bit.

On removing the links to this, I now have 8 bytes. :)

```
this.vendingKey = Conversions.hexStringToByteArray(vendingKey);
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(vendingKey, 16);
this.vendingKey = bigInteger.toByteArray();
```