# Java byte array comparison of MessageDigest SHA1 result and original hash value?

Tags: java, arrays, compare, message-digest

I would like to compare two byte arrays. One is calculated from plaintext with `MessageDigest` SHA1, the other is the hex itself in byte array, without calculation.

`MessageDigest` returns 20 byte long result, `String.getBytes()` returns 40 byte long array. `bytesToHex()` function is the same that was provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338/1424766), used only for printing.

**The question:**

How can I convert a string to byte array (and then compare with one calculated with `MessageDigest`) without the additional overhead? String comparison with `bytesToHex()` and `.toUppercase()` is working, but not an option, since speed is cruital in the application.

**The code:**

```
 MessageDigest md;

    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        byte[] toEncode = "test".getBytes();
        byte[] encoded = md.digest(toEncode);

        System.out.println("String to encode:\t\t" + new String(toEncode));
        System.out.println("Encoded in hex:\t\t\t" + bytesToHex(encoded));
        System.out.println("Encoded length:\t\t\t" + encoded.length);


        byte[] hash = new String("a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3").getBytes(); // "test" representation in SHA1

        System.out.println("\nHash to compare with:\t\t" + new String(hash));
        System.out.println("Hash length:\t\t\t" + hash.length);
        System.out.println("Two byte array equals:\t\t" + Arrays.equals(hash, encoded));
        System.out.println("Two equals in string:\t\t" + new String(hash).equals(bytesToHex(encoded).toLowerCase()));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**The result:**

```
String to encode:           test
Encoded in hex:             A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3
Encoded length:             20

Hash to compare with:       a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
Hash length:                40
Two byte array equals:      false
Two equals in string:       true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not decoding your hex representation to bytes. If you would, for example using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119453/3558960), the two arrays would match:

```
try {
    byte[] encoded = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest("test".getBytes());
    byte[] hash = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3");

    System.out.println("Two byte array equals:\t\t" + Arrays.equals(hash, encoded));
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```