# Java can't decrypt string encrypted in PHP

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Hello everyone i have string encrypted in PHP by `openssl_encrypt` with algorithm 'aes-256-cbc'

Key: `C4E30455853D4949A8E91B2C366BE9DE`

Vector: `5686044872102713`

Encrypted string: `ak9YSTd6RXU5TENocUxQUGxieVhpZ3VqSlFiQUdndGZrbVJvbEliTGZjZz0=`

And here is my Java function for decrypt:

```
public static String Decrypt_AES_FromBase64(String AEncryptedText, String AKey32Bytes, String AVectorNum16Bytes) {
        try { 
            byte[] vEncryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(AEncryptedText);

            Key SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(AKey32Bytes.getBytes(), "AES");
            IvParameterSpec vSpec = new IvParameterSpec(AVectorNum16Bytes.getBytes());

            Cipher vCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            vCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SecretKey, vSpec);

            return new String(vCipher.doFinal(vEncryptedBytes));
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Common.mContext.getLogger().log(e.toString());
            return "";
        }
    }
```

When i try to decrypt i have error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Can somebody tell what the wrong?

Comment: Not the highlighted problem but AKey32Bytes.getBytes() converts the characters into their character codes but you probably want to convert if from hexadecimal digits to binary: [In Java, how do I convert a hex string to a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890174/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-hex-string-to-a-byte[\])  There is some ambiguity about what to do with 5686044872102713.

Comment: I have changed to IvParameterSpec vSpec = new IvParameterSpec(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(AVectorNum16Bytes));

And now i have new error: "Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long"

Comment: The encrypted string is double Base64 encoded, there is no reason for that.

Comment: Probably the IV is not hex (there are no a-f characters) and an AES IV must be 16-bytes. An IV should instead be random bytes per encryption, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encrypted string `AKey32Bytes` is double Base64 encoded.

Instead of `AKey32Bytes.getBytes()` you need to double Base64 decode the encrypted data to binary.

Encrypted string:
`ak9YSTd6RXU5TENocUxQUGxieVhpZ3VqSlFiQUdndGZrbVJvbEliTGZjZz0=`

After one Base64 decode:
`jOXI7zEu9LChqLPPlbyXigujJQbAGgtfkmRolIbLfcg=`

After a second Base64 decode (displayed in hex because it is not binary):
`8CE5C8EF312EF4B0A1A8B3CF95BC978A0BA32506C01A0B5F9264689486CB7DC8`

That is what needs to be provided to the decryption function.

The decrypted result is:
(in hex) `257531362A2179704B40577255516272`
(in ASCII): "%u16*!ypK@WrUQbr" (all valid ASCII characters)

Note: there is a full block of PKCS#7 padding (in hex): `10101010101010101010101010101010`

As much as it pains me to say this, from the correct padding I can assume the decryption was successful.

See Cryptomathic [AES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/aescalc?key=4334453330343535383533443439343941384539314232433336364245394445&iv=35363836303434383732313032373133&input=8CE5C8EF312EF4B0A1A8B3CF95BC978A0BA32506C01A0B5F9264689486CB7DC8&mode=cbc&action=Decrypt&output=C546B2413F9A065F3EB6E6C00144C19664E997DF54874AD15E5EE7CC16613C9BA8832020BCEA95EC02AC7AA9AB6D1166)