# Insert into select with uuid

Tags: hibernate, hql

Taken following HQL statement:

```
final String HQL_TEMPLATE =
        "insert into UserWidget (position, user, widget, uuid)" +
        "select 0, u, w, concat('uuid-', u.id, w.id) " +
        "from User u, Widget w " +
        "where ...";
```

The fourth field of the insert properties is uuid. Currently I got it working using a concatenation of several id's but I would prefer to have an actual  generated uuid instead. Is this possible? Is there some equivalent for Oracle's sys_guid in HQL?

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846786/configure-hibernate-to-use-oracles-sys-guid-for-primary-key

Comment: Hi Ish, thanks, I had tried that but the problem is that the uuid needs to be part of the insert properties or it will need be set. I can add it to the insert properties but have nothing to add to the select clause. Simply doing: `insert into UserWidget (position, user, widget, uuid) select 0, u, w, uuid`does not work (No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode).